# RequireJS slowing down page load time

Tags: performance, asynchronous, requirejs, amd

One week ago I had some trouble with my web app getting bigger and bigger, and realized I had to find some kind of async JS loader, so I could load scripts when I really needed them.

I found requireJS and read a lot about it and AMD. Everything seems just right, it would help me organize my code in modules and I would have all the async load/dependencies resolving benefits.

My app is a single page one, all HTML is rendered in the browser using templates. I used grunt to concatenate and minify all my JS together and loaded it by script tags.

The load time of my application (I measured it by setting a variable in the `<head>` using `performance.now()`, and another one in the application render function) was around 90ms.

But my surprise was, after changing the core of my application to work with requireJS, and using the optimization tool to concatenate and minify everything, the load time raised up to 150ms.

I just think it's very strange, because on both cases all JS was concatenated in one file. I would understand if requireJS had to make another request to get my app.js, but it doesn't.

So - my question is:
Is there any way to make requireJS load faster? Is there any workaround? Or any alternative?

I thoroughly searched on google for similar problems but couldn't find any hint.

-- edit:

I created this jsFiddle to show you what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/fedevegili/Nhq3q/

As you can see, the "start" means the time after requirejs was loaded and before defining "Test".

"Execution" means the time when "Test" content was executed.

"Done" means the callback time.

I can't figure out why it takes almost 78ms just to call a function that was just defined.

My test result was:

```
Start: 2ms
Executed: 80ms
Callback: 81ms
```

-- edit2

I just tried the same JSFiddle using curljs: http://jsfiddle.net/fedevegili/67rBB/

My test results were

```
Testing with curljs --

Start: 1ms
Executed: 1ms
Callback: 55ms
```

As you can see, the code executes as soon as it is defined. Further testing I found out that with curljs the code gets executed as it is defined, and requirejs executes it when it is required.

I'll have to sticky with curljs because of this difference.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean, but for my tests I didn't make any ajax calls. It was just static html and one js file with concatenated stuff.

Comment: I'm running a local apache server.

Comment: Please take a look at the JSFiddle that I just added.

Comment: Added another fiddle comparing curljs vs requirejs. Interesting results.